# FPGA Audio Codec Initialization

Tags: audio-recording, fpga, i2c

Using a FPGA board, how to initialize the audio codec chip, WM8731, to 16-bit mode at 8 kHz sampling rate, and the input coming from the LINE IN terminal? I have no idea how to start working on the quuestion. Can any body please help me out

Answer (score 1):

WM8731 need to be programmed with initialization parameters for it to work.

1. Ask for the codec evaluation board from the Wolfson, the evaluation board comes with the source code for configuring the codecs.
2. This codec can be programed with SPI interface and 2 wire MPU interface. You can also learn more about this at http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~sedwards/classes/2008/4840/
3. http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/sound/soc/codecs/wm8731.c

Comment: Thanks a lot Lalin but I'm a beginner in VHDL and FPGA. I'm not understanding anything. My aim is to make a voice recorder. Can u please suggest me how to start on the project?
Thanks in advance :)